# Outlook 2010 HTML Display: Newsletter displays fine on one's computer, but not another

Tags: html, outlook

Most of us in our office environment uses Outlook 2010 for our email needs. We'll eventually upgrade to higher versions of Office, but that may be sometime later.

I have worked with a vendor to create an internal email template, to be used by a colleague who is meant to just input text within the template and send it out. The odd part is the template works well on my computer, but not on the colleague's. The vendor has already optimized the template to be good for Outlook 2010.

On my colleague's computer, it seems like the template has added additional padding between the images or table cells. The email she'll eventually send out will have this additional padding as well.

Is there any settings I need to do on her Outlook 2010 settings?

NOTE: It's in HTML, and not saved as an Outlook Template yet.

Answer (score 0):

Display A = How it looks like on your com
Display B = How it looks like on colleague

You copied the HTML code and it turns out to be Display A. However, when you sent, Outlook converts the HTML into their syntax, which in this case you will see a `mso` in front of some CSS classes.

The resulted display on your colleague is Display B, the modified version by Outlook. When she forward or send out this email, she will be sending out with `mso` tag as well and not in the HTML format you sent.

Comment: Hi. When my colleague loads the HTML on her own computer (without receiving it straight from me), she'll have this problem.

Comment: @kosherjellyfish check for outlook default settings like font etc